# Travel direction of values in nested function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What happens when I write this function, at a "flow" level, so to speak? That is, how do values move between objects?

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // ...
})
```

My assumptions: is `$` passed to its internal function by `jQuery`? or is it grabbed by `function()` from the `window` global object/plugin definition etc, then passed to `jQuery` function?  Outer to inner or inner to outer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is just like any other callback function. `$` is a parameter variable, which gets its value from the argument supplied by the caller.

In this case, the caller is the `jQuery` function. And when it's calling this function, it passes itself as the argument.

It has nothing to do with the global variable named `$`. You could just as well write

```
jQuery(function(jq) {
  // ...
});
```

Then inside the function, you could write something like `jq('.classname').hide()` instead of `$('.classname').hide()` to call jQuery methods.

The code you posted is used in case the global variable `$` is used for something *other* than jQuery. This ensures that within the body of the callback function, you can use `$` as the jQuery abbreviation without conflicting with that other use.

Comment: As far as I know, a function _transforms_ a value and returns a transformed value. Optionally does things and returns void, but it acts as the _recever_ of some value. Functions do not pass values, they are passed values -- correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If the argument to a function is another function, it can call that function. Consider `Array.forEach()`

Comment: Or `$("#someid").on("click", function() { ... })`. This arranges for the function to be called when a click occurs on the specified element.

Comment: So if a function contains a function, the outer triggers the inner one, which trasforms a value, then the inner function it returns a value to the outer who trasforms it. Otherwise it just trasforms a value. Right?

Comment: Functions don't always transform and/or return values. E.g. `console.log("foo")` just displays the string on the console, it doesn't return anything. It doesn't transform anything, either, unless you consider the state of the console to be a transformation of the `"foo"` argument.

Comment: Years ago the term for these was "subroutine" or "procedure". But in modern programming languages they're called functions, even though they don't correspond to the mathematical notion.

Comment: In `console.log("foo")` `log("foo")` trasforms a value (in this case the trasformation is naught, so we can say it does not transform the value) and returns it to the `console` object, which administers the console behavior. Sorry for nagging, I'm trying to understand the topic :)

Comment: I'm not going to give you a computer science course here.

Comment: Forget about the mathematical concept of transforming values. A function is a way to represent a sequence of actions as a unit. It can optionally be named, so that it can be used as a level of abstraction in the rest of the program. It may take inputs and/or return values.

Comment: And in most modern languages, functions are first-class objects that can be passed as values. This allows creating higher-order functions that take functions as parameters and/or return them as values.

Comment: There are also "closures", which are functions that capture variable bindings from the surrounding context, which allows them to have state (similar to object methods).

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right in your assumption @Manaus.

`jQuery()` is a caller function with a callback function that receives `$` as an argument to be used as a **local variable**. Now, since `$` is an argument you can name it whatever you want like `myJQ` and it will still work fine.

The advantage to using this syntax is $ may be defined/set as something else globally in your code, BUT JQuery will ensure that there is no conflict in the meaning of $ being referenced from within the caller JQuery() and from outside.

`$(function() { ... })` IS THE SAME AS `jQuery(function($) { ... })` but THE LATTER also makes $ available inside the function no matter what it's set on the outside. Also `jQuery(function($) { ... })` === `jQuery(function(myJQ) { ... })`.